# Get Name/ID from button

Tags: java, javafx

I just created my first javaFX program. It contains 55 Buttons and I trying to find a way to get the id of the buttons that was pressed and save it into a varible without creating one handler for each button.

**Edit:** I managed to fill 8 GridPane's with a total of 160 buttons and every buttons gives me the name back. I added the solution in case someone is interested.

Thanks James for your time and help!

```
    for(int i = 1; i < 9; i++ ) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                String buttonText = "" + buttoncounter;
                Button button = new Button(buttonText);
                switch(i){
                    case 1: gp1.add(button, k, j);
                        break;
                    case 2: gp2.add(button, k, j);
                        break;
                    case 3: gp3.add(button, k, j);
                        break;
                    case 4: gp4.add(button, k, j);
                        break;
                    case 5: gp5.add(button, k, j);
                        break;
                    case 6: gp6.add(button, k, j);
                        break;
                    case 7: gp7.add(button, k, j);
                        break;
                    case 8: gp8.add(button, k, j);
                }
                button.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
                button.setOnAction(e -> {
                    buttonPressed = Integer.parseInt(buttonText);
                });
                buttoncounter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use name of the button using `button.getName()`

Comment: The buttons are created as soon the program starts. How can I access it with button.getName() if the button has not created yet? Sorry but a I'm new at this and I still don't get it.

Comment: @nullpointer There is no `name` property in [`javafx.scene.control.Button`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html) @Michael95 Why create buttons that are never used in the `initialize` method?

Comment: If you have 55 buttons, it seems like it would already be way too much code to create them in FXML. Why don't you create the buttons in Java (e.g. in the controller or in a separate class)? Then you can create them in a loop and register a handler with each one easily, without having to write 55 different methods or work with fragile ids, etc.

Comment: @fabian I'm new at this and as I mentioned and I thought I could create them in the initialize method by using a for loop so I do not have to manually declare 50+ buttons. But you are right they never were used

Comment: @James_D Do I really have to create 55 Buttons (maybe I need even more) one by one? Is there no way to do it programmatically?

Comment: @Michael95 Yes, that's what I'm saying - do it programmatically (i.e. not in FXML). Then you can register a different event handler with each one, and you don't need to get the id, etc.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you showed your FXML file?

Comment: Thanks for your help James. It never crossed my mind to be honest. I'm using the SceneBuilder and c&p the panels(each with 20 Buttons) over and over again. But it is good to know that it is possible, even if I can not see how an algorithm can place all the buttons in the right place. I will keep that in mind. What I meant, however, was a way to declare the buttons inside the controller without declaring each button (150+) on by one and using 150 seperate handlers. There have to be a much easier way. Oh here is the .fxml file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0qAsFRVXxzFM0VQRHdJRUpkb0E

Comment: @Michael95 Don't post links to code. [Edit] your question to include the FXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the buttons programmatically (i.e. not in FXML). That way you can easily register a different handler with each, and you don't need to look up the button by id or via its text, etc.

For example, in your FXML file, do

```xml
<TilePane fx:id="buttonPane" />
```

And then in the controller:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TilePane buttonPane ;

    public void initialize() {
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 55 ; i++) {
            String buttonText = "Button "+i ;
            Button button = new Button(buttonText);
            buttonPane.getChildren().add(button);
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                // whatever you need here: you know the button pressed is the 
                // one and only button the handler is registered with
                System.out.println(buttonText + " clicked");
            });
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I would upvote this but unfortunately I can't. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

i know this is late, but you can try this instead

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println(((Button)event.getSource()).getText());
}
```

or get id

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println(((Button)event.getSource()).getId());
}
```

in the FXML, you can add onAction

```
<Button fx:id="viewBtn" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="View" />
```